# how to show hide&hide buttons for specific user in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, security-roles

how can I show button for specific user and hide it for another one based on security role in ASP.NET MVC 2.

For example if I have Create button in my view how to show it only for admin and hide it for any other user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if (User.IsInRole("admins"))
{ %>
    <input type="button" value="Create" />
<% } %>
```

Where `"admins"` is the name of your Role